# Many to Many association with 3 participating classes - form generating

Tags: forms, symfony, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

I have three simple entities.

```
class Product {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductsCategories", mappedBy="category")
    */
    private $categories;

    //..

class ProductsCategories {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
    */
    private $product;

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
    */
    private $category;

    //..


class Category {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductsCategories", mappedBy="product")
    */
    private $products;

    //..
```

I want to create many to many association with additional class in order to add additional fields. My problem is that I don't know how to generate form field, here is my form type

```
    //..
    ->add('categories', 'entity', [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
        'choice_label' => function($category, $key, $index) {
            return $category->getName();
        },
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'expanded' => false,
    ])
    //..
```

But when I submit the form this errors shows up:

`Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\Product#$categories", got "AppBundle\Entity\Category" instead.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
Sorry, I've not understand that you want a ManyToMany with Attributes, I think you need create a ProductCategoryType, with some fields for your "attributes" and a field EntityType on Category.
Then in the ProductType, you add a CollectionType of ProductCategoryType.

---

Your entity aren't correct, you may use ManyToMany relation, and no OneToMany on each Entity, that mach on an other entity. Else Doctrine don't do the relation between the 2 entity.
You need just have Prouct and Category entity, with a ManyToMany relation. I give you an exemple for a ManyToMany bidirectional.

```
class Product {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="products")
    */
    private $categories;

    //..


class Category {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="categories")
    */
    private $products;

    //..
```

You need add some methods in Product:

```
__construct() {
  $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}

addCategory(Category $category) {
  $this->categories[] = $category;
}

removeCategory(Category $category) {
  $this->categories->removeElement($caegory);
}

getCategories() {
  return $this->categories();
}
```

Do the same for Categories (replace Category by Product and Categories by Category. Then you can modify the addCategory method like this:

```
addCategory(Category $category) {
  $this->categories[] = $category;
  $category->addProduct($this);
}
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: No, no, no, you don't understand, with your example I can't add additional fields to the newly created third table. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional `Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.`

Comment: Sorry, I've not understand that you want a ManyToMany with Attributes, I think you need create a ProductCategoryType, with some fields for your "attributes" and a field EntityType on Category. Then in the ProductType, you add a CollectionType of ProductCategoryType.